# Can Wolverine be considered a mutant?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

When the first X-Men movie came out in the nineties (or 2000),I went for nostalgic reasons. Since then the MCU has exploded - my question is simply **can Wolverine be considered a mutant**; and were there changes to his origins in the movie vs. the comics.

Comment: The 90's, eh? Where do you live that you got the movie before the rest of the world. It didn't premiere anywhere else until 2000.

Comment: Oops - my bad (lol). I just knew it was a long time ago.  By the way, the upcoming tv series, Midnight, Texas also features Mutants, or are they called something different?

Comment: The show *Midnight, Texas* has no ties to the X-Men, regardless of what they may be calling their characters. The upcoming show *Gifted* does.

Comment: Also, X-Men (the movie series) is *not* part of the MCU.

Comment: I think this question needs to be edited for clarification. Are you asking about the movies or the comics?

Answer (score 10):

Wolverine is a fairly old mutant (in the X-Men cinematic universe he was born somewhere in the early 19th century as [Wolverine Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_Origins:_Wolverine) starts with him as a child in 1845). His mutant parts involve

1. Bone claws
   [image]
2. Superhuman healing (hence his long life)

The Adamantium bonded to his skeleton is actually a poison (something of a plot point in [logan](/questions/tagged/logan)), but his mutant healing factor can easily keep pace with the damage. The Adamantium was added as part of the [Weapon X program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_X_(story_arc))

Comment: how did they know he was a mutant when they "kidnapped" him for the program - did Logan himself realize he was a mutant. Did they do the same to his brother (Sabretooth?).

Comment: Wolverine volunteered for the program and was not abducted. They knew he was a mutant and of his abilities prior to the surgery, which is why they hoped he would survive.

Comment: Pretty sure that was the late 18th century, since they show him fighting in the War Between the States.

Comment: @Paul Double checked and Origins starts in 1845. So early-mid 19th century (edited to reflect that). Civil War was 1861-1865. Revolutionary war would be 18th century

Comment: @Paul  To be specific, the century is always one higher than the first two digits of most of it.  E.g. the 18th century was 1701 to 1800.  The Civil War was 1861-1865, so 19th century.  Currently, 2017 is 21st century.

Comment: Ok, guys, but certainly not late 19th century which was what was originally claimed.  But thanks, I was well aware that 1800s is 19th century.